# Error con Scanner al pedir un entero nextInt() y despues un String nextLine()

Tags: java, archivo

Estoy  pidiendo una cadena para insertarla en un archivo, si el archivo no existe lo creo
y si existe lo reescribo, parece sencillo pero por algun motivo no me pide la palabra, se salta la instruccion. No entiendo nada por que si vuelvo a pedirlo una segunda vez si me hace caso.
Me gustaria saber a quees debido y  que solucion hay.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FicheroBytess {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cadena,nombreFich;



        System.out.println("Escribe el texto que va contener el fichero"); 
        cadena=in.nextLine();//leola linea compleata ylo guardo en un String
        System.out.println("Escribe el nombre del fichero");
        nombreFich=in.nextLine();//leo la linea completa y la guardo en un string
        File f = new File(nombreFich);// defino la ubicacion
        FileOutputStream fos; //declaro el stream
        try {
        if (!(f.exists())) {//si no existe el fichero
            System.out.println("No existe entonces lo creo");
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(nombreFich); //creo el fichero aqui tengo dudas   //flujo de salida de archivo   
                    char c[] =cadena.toCharArray();    //guardo el String en un array de caracteres
                    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) { //recorro el array carcter por carcter
                        try {
                            fos.write((byte)c[i]);   //escribo cada posicion del caracter en el archivo conwrite
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }       

            System.out.println("archivo "+f+" creado");

        }           
                int opcion;
                do {//do while con un tres sale del programa
                    do {//perite un numero entre 1y 3
                        System.out.println("Existe y menu\n" //menu
                                + "1. Reescribir fichero\n"
                                + "2. Añadir al final\n"
                                + "3. Atras\n");
                    opcion = in.nextInt();//Elegimos opciondel menu


                    switch (opcion) {
                    case 1://como elijo uno
                        System.out.println("Escribe una cadena");//mensaje
                         cadena=in.nextLine();//IMPORTANTE  AQUI PASA DE LARGO!!!!! NO LO ENTIENDO!!!!
                         //cadena=in.nextLine();   //si lo repito una segunda vez si lo leee no lo entiendo!!!
                         fos = new FileOutputStream(nombreFich);

                         char c[] =cadena.toCharArray();//igual que el anterior
                            System.out.println(cadena);
                            System.out.println(cadena.length());
                            for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                                try {
                                    fos.write((byte)c[i]);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        break;
                    case 2://aqui aun no he llegado
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(nombreFich,true);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    } while (opcion < 1 || opcion > 3);
                } while (opcion != 3);//







         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                in.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El fallo está a la hora de recoger la variable entera **`opcion`**.

## Cómo limpiar el buffer de entrada en Java

> Cuando en un programa se leen por teclado datos `numéricos` y datos de tipo `carácter` o `String` debemos tener en cuenta que al introducir los datos y pulsar intro estamos también introduciendo en el buffer de entrada el intro.
>   Es decir, cuando en un programa introducimos un datos y pulsamos el intro como final de entrada, el carácter intro también pasa al buffer de entrada.
>   Buffer de entrada si se introduce un 5: 5\n
>
> En esta situación, la instrucción:
>
> `n = sc.nextInt();`
>
> Asigna a n el valor 5 pero el intro permanece en el buffer
>   Buffer de entrada después de leer el entero: \n
>
> Si ahora se pide que se introduzca por teclado una cadena de caracteres:
>
> `System.out.print("Introduzca su nombre: ");`
>   `nombre = sc.nextLine();  //leer un String`
>
> El método nextLine() extrae del buffer de entrada todos los caracteres hasta llegar a un intro y elimina el intro del buffer.
>   En este caso asigna una cadena vacía a la variable nombre y limpia el intro. Esto provoca que el programa no funcione correctamente, ya que no se detiene para que se introduzca el nombre.

**Solución:**

> Se debe limpiar el buffer de entrada si se van a leer datos de tipo carácter a > continuación de la lectura de datos numéricos.
>
> La forma más sencilla de limpiar el buffer de entrada en Java es ejecutar la instrucción:
>
> `sc.nextLine();`

```
opcion = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());//Elegimos opciondel menu
```

---

Haciendo esto ya te debería funcionar correctamente.

**P.d.**
También podríamos hacerlo así para entender mejor lo que estamos haciendo.

```
opcion = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
```

No a la inversa..

> **Fuente** [Java Scanner para lectura de datos](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/java-scanner.html)

Comment: Es cierto  esto me arregla el problema, pero no lo entiendo que quisiste decir con el salto delinea y ademas siempre he pedido los enteros  con in.nextInt(); y por lo que veo el valor lo recojemos con nextLine();(String)  y lo transformamos a int.

Comment: Digamos que hay que darle un salto de línea después de introducir el valor, para que nos lea la siguiente parte de tu código.

Comment: He editado la respuesta para un mayor entendimiento. Saludos!!

Comment: Muchas gracias con tu explicacion y el link que dejaste lo entendi del todo. http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/java-scanner.htmlJ

Comment: Gracias! a ti. :)