# Java: mensaje "No existe" antes de meter el dato

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de java sobre objetos insertados en un ArrayList.
Pongo trozos de código a ver si consigo expresar el error:

Objeto :

```
public class Articulo {
    private String codigo;
    private String descripcion;
    private short existencias;
    ...
```

ArrayList:

```
public class Almacen {
  private ArrayList <Articulo> almacenPrincipal = new ArrayList(); 
  Iterator <Articulo> itr;

  //método para cargar 4 artículos en el almacén
  public void cargarAlmacen(){
    //se crean los 4 objetos de tipo artículo
    Articulo articulo1 = new Articulo();
    Articulo articulo2 = new Articulo("AA.123A", "tornillos", (short)9);
    Articulo articulo3 = new Articulo("BB.111B", "tuercas");
    Articulo articulo4 = new Articulo(articulo1);
    //se modifican los artículos
    articulo3.setExistencias((short)500);
    articulo4.setCodigo("CC.222C");
    articulo4.setDescripcion("arandelas");
    articulo4.setExistencias((short)500);
    //se añaden los 4 artículos al arraylist almacenPrincipal
    almacenPrincipal.add (articulo1);
    almacenPrincipal.add (articulo2);
    almacenPrincipal.add (articulo3);
    almacenPrincipal.add (articulo4);
  }

  //método para realizar la carga de un nuevo artículo en el almacén
  public void cargarArticulo(){
    System.out.println ("\nIntroduzca código de articulo: ");
    String codigo = codigoVal();
    if (!comprobarRepetidos(codigo)){    
        System.out.println ("\nIntroduzca descripción del articulo: ");
        String descripcion = descripcionVal();
        System.out.println ("\nIntroduzca cantidad de existencias: ");
        short existencias = existenciasVal();
        Articulo articuloNuevo = new Articulo (codigo, descripcion, existencias);
        almacenPrincipal.add (articuloNuevo);
    }
  }

  //método para validar si el código introducido es conforme:
  //empieza por dos letras mayúsculas + punto + entre 1 y 3 dígitos numéricos + mínimo 1 letra mayúscula o minúscula
  public String codigoVal(){
    boolean codigoError=true;
    String codigo;
    Pattern patron=Pattern.compile("^([A-Z]{2})([\\.]{1})(\\d{1,3})([a-zA-Z]{1,})$");
    do{
        codigo = teclado.nextLine();
        Matcher m=patron.matcher(codigo);
        if (m.matches()){
            codigoError=false;
        }else{
           System.err.println ("El código no es válido. Vuelva a intentarlo: ");
        }
    }while (codigoError);
    return codigo;
  }

  //método para buscar un artículo
  public boolean buscarArticulo(){
    itr = almacenPrincipal.iterator();
    String codigoBuscado = codigoVal();
    while (itr.hasNext()){
        Articulo articuloBuscado = itr.next();
        if(articuloBuscado.getCodigo().equals(codigoBuscado)){
           System.out.println ("Los datos del artículo son: \n"+articuloBuscado.mostrarDatos());
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
...
```

Clase Principal(Main):

```
System.out.println("\nMenú Artículos");
System.out.println("1. Añadir artículo.");
System.out.println("2. Buscar artículo.");
System.out.println("3. Eliminar artículo.");
System.out.println("4. Visualizar almacén.");
System.out.println("5. Salir.");
System.out.println("\nIntroduzca nº de opción: ");

opcion = teclado.nextByte();
   switch (opcion){
     case 1:
       almacenPrincipal.cargarArticulo();
       break;
     case 2:
       System.out.println("Introduzca código a buscar: ");
       if (!almacenPrincipal.buscarArticulo()){
         System.out.println ("El artículo no existe.");
       }
       break;
     case 3:
       System.out.println("Introduzca código a eliminar: ");
       almacenPrincipal.borrarArticulo();
       break;
     case 4:
       almacenPrincipal.visualizarAlmacen();
       break;
     case 5:
       System.out.println ("Fin del programa. Adiós.");
       break;
     default:
       System.err.println ("El nº de opción no es válido. Vuelva a intentarlo.");
}
```

Si meto opción 2, busca el artículo bien, sin problema.

Si luego meto la opción 1, el nuevo artículo lo carga bien.

Si después meto otra vez la opción 2, antes de pedirme el código del artículo a buscar me sale mensaje de error de que "*el artículo no existe*", y ya después me deja buscar el artículo, y lo encuentra y lo muestra. La búsqueda es con iterador porque lo exige el enunciado.

**No sé por qué, si ejecuto antes la opción 1 que la 2 me sale ese mensaje de error antes de dejarme meter el código**:
[image: Ejecución]

Es mi primer mensaje. Espero que se entienda bien la pregunta.
**Muchas a gracias a tod@s por la ayuda**.

Un saludo,
chache ;)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error con Scanner al pedir un entero nextInt() y despues un String nextLine()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163982/error-con-scanner-al-pedir-un-entero-nextint-y-despues-un-string-nextline)

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Has planteado la pregunta de una forma correcta (código, comportamiento esperado, comportamiento obtenido), pero creo que te convendría revisar lo que es un [mcve] para el futuro, tanto para hacer preguntas como para depurar tus problemas tú mismo; creo que si hubieras hecho ese trabajo es probable que hubieras visto que el problema venía de la entrada de datos y que hubieras encontrado la respuesta por tí mismo, y en el peor de los casos habría sido más fácil para la gente responderte.

Comment: Lo siento mucho, en el temario de Java todavía no se ha hablado de estos problemas de la entrada de datos, y ni siquiera sabía que existían, por lo tanto, imposible saber que el problema venía de allí.
Muchísimas gracias por la contestación.

Comment: Si no es que haya que disculparse, ya iría bien que todas las primeras preguntas fueran como la tuya. Y desde luego no tienes porqué saberlo todo sobre un lenguaje para preguntar. Simplemente te aconsejo que intentes reducir el problema a un [mcve] porque te será más fácil encontrar la solución (ya sea tú directamente, o porque otras personas lo tendrán más fácil para entender tu problema).

Comment: Puede que tengas problemas con el buffer de entrada de datos. La clase `Scanner` suele dar problemas al introducir un dato y pulsar `Enter`, ya que lo almacena como un salto de línea en el buffer `\n` y hay que limpiarlo con la instrucción `nextLine();`.

Answer (score 0):

Pues ahora estoy haciendo un ejercicio de mapas y me pasa algo parecido. El problema debe estar en cómo construyo yo el bucle do-while. Algo falla, que la primera vez lo hace bien, pero la segunda vez se salta pedir el primer dato:

```
//método para añadir elementos al mapa
void anadeElemento(){
  boolean empresaExiste = true;
  String cif;
  String nombre = null;
  int numTrabajadores = 0;
  do{
    System.out.println ("Introduzca CIF de empresa:");
    cif = teclado.nextLine();
      if (!mapaEmpresas.containsKey(cif)){
        System.out.println ("Introduzca nombre de empresa:");
        nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("Introduzca número de trabajadores de la empresa: ");
        numTrabajadores = comprobarEntero();
        empresaExiste = false;
      }else{
        System.err.println ("El CIF ya existe. Pruebe de nuevo:");
      }  
    }while (empresaExiste);
```

La salida por pantalla es:

```
Introduzca CIF de empresa:
A34304044
Introduzca nombre de empresa:
El Corte Inglés
Introduzca número de trabajadores de la empresa:
2000

Menú Asociación:
1. Añadir empresa...

Introduzca nº de opción:
1
Introduzca CIF de empresa:
Introduzca nombre de empresa:
```

La segunda vez no pide CIF y salta directamente a pedir el nombre de la empresa.
No sé porqué funciona así. Estoy empezando en esto del Java y no entiendo el problema.
Muchas gracias de antemano.
Chache ;)

Comment: Hola Cache, recuerda que si deseas agregar actualizaciones a tu pregunta usa el botón Editar, ya que aquí es la zona de respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que lo que ocurre es lo siguiente:

A la hora de preguntar por la opción, estás leyendo 1 solo byte (o caracter).

Entonces cuando tu ingresas la opción 2, realmente estás escribiendo: 2 + enter, es decir, 2 + salto de línea. O `2\n`

Al leer solo un byte, solo te quedas con el `2`.

Después, para validar el código lo primero que haces es `teclado.nextLine();` que probablemente recupere hasta el final de línea. Pero como no habías consumido la línea anterior, simplemente obtiene `\n`. Al intentar validar `\n` contra tu expresión regular no se cumple y muestra el error.

Una manera para que lo compruebes es que una vez que haces: `codigo = teclado.nextLine();`, imprimas el valor que hay en `código` así se verá claro (debería aparecer un salto de línea)

Comment: Efectivamente, creo que será esto lo que ocurre. Bien explicado.

Comment: Comprueba a ver si es el caso, aunque parece que sí. Para arreglarlo, quizás podrías consumir la línea completa cuando vas a elegir la opción, y antes de hacer `switch (opcion){` eliminas el salto de línea, para de esta forma quedarte solo con el número (y no de problemas en el switch). Después, cuando escojas una opción no habrá ninguna línea pendiente de consumir y podrás ingresar el código sin que aparezca el mensaje antes de hora. @smt