# Mis Arreglos funcionan mal

Tags: java, netbeans, eclipse, java-8

el problema es que el usuario pone  de cuantas posisiones quiere su arreglo por ejemplo de 3 y cuando el programa le dice que introdusca el valor para cada posision las dos primeras  posisiones se llenan antomaticamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
introducir el código aquí



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n;
        System.out.println("¿Cuantas Materias Hay?");
        n = in.nextInt();
        String[ ] alu = new String[n];
        double[ ] cali = new double[n];

           System.out.println("Ingrese Todos los nombres de los alumnos ");
          for(int i=0; i<=n-i; i++) {

              alu[i] = in.nextLine();

          }
          System.out.println("Ingrese todas las calificacioness de los alumnos");
          for(int i=1; i<=n-1; i++) {

              cali[i] = in.nextDouble();
          }


}
```

}

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error con Scanner al pedir un entero nextInt() y despues un String nextLine()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163982/error-con-scanner-al-pedir-un-entero-nextint-y-despues-un-string-nextline)

Comment: El segundo for empiezas por 1 en vez de 0. Cambialo a "for(int i=0; i<=n-1; i++)"