# Ciclo FOR imprime dos veces: "Ingrese el nombre del trabajador"

Tags: java, bucle-for

me encuentro practicando java y me propuse hacer un ejercicio para poder aprender y comprender el lenguaje, pero llevo varios minutos calentándome la cabeza con un error que no logro solucionar, quizás sea algo muy básico, pero mi nivel también lo es. Este es mi código:

```java
package Main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejecutador {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Scanner lectura = new Scanner (System.in);
        int numTrabajadores;

        System.out.println("¿Cuantos trabajadores ingresara?");
        numTrabajadores = lectura.nextInt();

        String[] nombTrabajadores = new String[numTrabajadores];

        for (int i=0; i<numTrabajadores; i++){
            System.out.println((i+1)+" - Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: ");
            nombTrabajadores[i] = lectura.nextLine();
        }

    }

}
```

Lo que la consola muestra, es lo siguiente:

```
¿Cuantos trabajadores ingresara?
3
1 - Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: 
2 - Ingrese el nombre del trabajador:
```

No logro comprender porque la consola me imprime dos veces "Ingrese el nombre del trabajador".

Gracias por adelantado :)

Comment: Después de leer un número con nextInt, debes usar nextLine para "vaciar" el retorno de línea almacenado antes de de pedir más datos

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error con Scanner al pedir un entero nextInt() y despues un String nextLine()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163982/error-con-scanner-al-pedir-un-entero-nextint-y-despues-un-string-nextline)

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que cuando entra en el ciclo for y te pide el nombre del trabajador, le das la instrucción que haga un salto de linea, lo cual hace que te imprima dos veces el mensaje

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

        Scanner lectura = new Scanner (System.in);
        int numTrabajadores;

        System.out.println("¿Cuantos trabajadores ingresara?");
        numTrabajadores = lectura.nextInt();

        String[] nombTrabajadores = new String[numTrabajadores];

        for (int i=0; i<numTrabajadores; i++){
            System.out.println((i+1)+" - Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: ");
            nombTrabajadores[i] = lectura.next(); // quitamos Line para que no haga salto de linea
        }

    }
```

```
en consola muestra lo siguiente
¿Cuantos trabajadores ingresara?
3
1 - Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: 
amarillo
2 - Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: 
verde
3 - Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: 
rojo
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes sacar esta línea del `for`:

```
System.out.println((i+1)+" - Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: ");
```

Y yo le cambiaría el mensaje por:

"Ingrese el nombre de los trabajadores".

Si no sacas esa linea del `for`, cada vez que cicla, te imprime por pantalla ese mensaje.