# Quiero hacer una testeo, que al momento que el usuario digite un nombre de un libro "x", no sea igual a uno ya ingresado

Tags: java

Al momento que el usuario ingrese un libro, en este caso su título, no se encuentre repetido. Ayuda comunidad, muchas gracias :)

```
 System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de libros: ");
                librosAIngresar = n.nextInt();
                
                Libro _librosAIngresar[] = new Libro[librosAIngresar];
                for(int i=0; i<_librosAIngresar.length; i++){
                 _autor = n.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Autor: ");
                _autor = n.nextLine();
                System.out.print("");
                System.out.print("Titulo: ");
                _titulo = n.nextLine();
               
                /*do{
                    _librosAIngresar[i].setAutor(_autor);
                _librosAIngresar[i].setTituloLibro(_titulo);
                if(_librosAIngresar[i].getTituloLibro().equals(_titulo)){
                    System.out.println("Este titulo, ya está ingresado"); 
                }
                }while(!(_librosAIngresar[i].getTituloLibro().equals(_titulo)));*/
                
                /*if(!(_librosAIngresar[i].getTituloLibro().equals(_titulo))){
                _librosAIngresar[i].setAutor(_autor);
                _librosAIngresar[i].setTituloLibro(_titulo); 
                }else{
                   System.out.println("Ese título, ya está ingresado");                    
                }*/
//Intente de ambas formas, con un if, y un while, ayuda :(
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Dato1:*

si usas `nextInt()` y luego `nexLine()` debes limpiar el [buffer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163982/error-con-scanner-al-pedir-un-entero-nextint-y-despues-un-string-nextline/163985#163985)

*Dato2:*
si usas solo next() e ingresas `Victor Hugo` solo capturaras `Victor` obviaras el espacio

*Respuesta*

puedes apoyarte del uso de un `ArrayList` y su método [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection))

```
System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de libros: ");
int librosAIngresar = n.nextInt();
n.nextLine();
Libro _librosAIngresar[] = new Libro[librosAIngresar];
String autor;
String titulo;
ArrayList<String>lista=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<_librosAIngresar.length; i++){
             
                System.out.println("Autor: ");
                autor = n.nextLine();
                while (lista.contains(autor)){
                System.out.println("Autor ya ingresado,ingresar nuevo autor");  
                autor = n.nextLine();   
                }
                lista.add(autor);

                System.out.println("Titulo: ");
                titulo = n.nextLine();
                while (lista.contains(titulo)){
                System.out.println("titulo ya ingresado,ingresar nuevo titulo");  
                titulo = n.nextLine();  
                }
                lista.add(titulo);

            Libro libro=new Libro(autor,titulo);    
           _librosAIngresar[i]=libro;  
}
```

el método `contains` evaluara si el `ArrayList` contiene dato ingresado,de no ser así se guardara en el `ArrayList` de lo contrario te volverá a solicitar datos diferente,si fuera a ingresar mismo autor mismo titulo lo mejor es crear dos ArrayList uno para autor y otro para titulo ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, en si iba a utilizar ambos metodos (ya que estoy practicando, pero al momento de yo querer ingresar el titulo y el autor en el arreglo .. EJ:                     _librosAIngresar[i].setTituloLibro(_titulo);
Me sale la excepción :/, si me pudieras ayudar con ese problema, también te lo agradeceria bro, graciassss

Comment: Lo que sucede es que primero debes guardar el objeto creado en el array para poder acceder al valor que se va ah modificar mediante set cosa que no estabas haciendo,si queres hacer uso de set con el primer for solicita los datos crea los objetos y guardalos en el array y mediante otro evalua si se repiten los autores y titulos y ahora si solicita nuevos datos y has uso de setters

Comment: Pero como lo agrego al array, el nombre y el apellido?, si tienes tiempo, agregame al discord: Meliodasx31x