# Campo vacíos al dar la segunda vuelta al programa

Tags: java, eclipse, salto-de-linea

Estoy haciendo un programa para que se vaya introduciendo el número de alumnos que dese el usuario y después estos se muestren en un fichero.

El problema que tengo es que al dar la primera vuelta coge bien todos los campos pero al dar la segunda vuelta en adelante deja el campo nombre vacío.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        int opcion = 0;
        String nombreFile;
        boolean exit = false;
        int num;

        do {
            menuPrincipal();
            do {

                // VALIDAR NUMERO ENTERO
                try {
                    opcion = entrada.nextInt();
                    exit = true;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Debe introducir un número entero");
                    entrada.next();
                }

            } while (!exit);

        } while (opcion < salir || opcion > mostrarAlumnos);

        // OPCIONE DEL MENU
        switch (opcion) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Cerrando programa...");

            break;
        case crearFichero:
            System.out.print("Nombre del archivo: ");
            nombreFile = entrada.next();

            existeFichero(nombreFile);

            break;
        case selecionarFichero:
//          System.out.println("Nombre del archivo");
//          nombreFile = entrada.next();

            break;
        case cargarAlumnos:

            break;
        case mostrarAlumnos:

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

        static void datosAlumno(String nombreFile) {
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            System.out.println("Creando fichero...");
            File archivo = new File(nombreFile);
    
            int nia;
            String nombre;
            String apellidos;
            char genero;
            String ciclo;
            String curso;
            String grupo;
    
            System.out.print("Cuantos alumnos desea añadir: ");
            int num = entero();
    
            List<Alumno> datosAlumnos = new ArrayList<>(num);
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                System.out.println("Alumno " + (i + 1) + ": ");
    
                System.out.print("Nia: ");
                nia = entero();
    
                System.out.print("Nombre: ");
                nombre = entrada.next();
                entrada.next();
    
                System.out.print("Apellidos: ");
                apellidos = entrada.nextLine();
    
                System.out.print("Genero: ");
                genero = genero();
    
                System.out.print("Ciclo: ");
                ciclo = entrada.next();
    
                System.out.print("Curso: ");
                curso = entrada.next();
    
                System.out.print("Grupo: ");
                grupo = entrada.next();
    
    //          datosAlumnos.add(new Alumno(nia, grupo, grupo, genero, grupo, grupo, grupo));
    
                try {
                    BufferedWriter añadirAlumnos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo, true));
    
                    añadirAlumnos.write(nia);
                    añadirAlumnos.write(nombre);
                    añadirAlumnos.write(apellidos);
                    añadirAlumnos.write(genero);
                    añadirAlumnos.write(ciclo);
                    añadirAlumnos.write(curso);
                    añadirAlumnos.write(grupo);
                    añadirAlumnos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error al añadir los datos al archivo");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    
            }
    
        }

    static int entero() {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        // boolean exit = false;

        do {

            // VALIDAR NUMERO ENTERO
            try {
                return num = entrada.nextInt();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Debe introducir un número entero");
                // entrada.nextLine();

            }

        } while (true);

    }

    static char genero() {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        char genero;
        boolean exit = false;

        do {
            genero = entrada.next().charAt(0);
            if (genero == 'm' || genero == 'M') {
                exit = true;

            } else if (genero == 'f' || genero == 'F') {
                exit = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Dato incorrecto \nSolo se admite (M o F)");
                System.out.print("Introduzca otra vez el dato: ");
            }

        } while (!exit);
        return genero;
    }
```

Comment: Al capturar el nombre estas poniendo `entrada.next( );`esto hará que te vuelva a soliCItar un dato (por eso el supuesto espacio vació) si lo que buscas es limpiar el [buffer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163982/error-con-scanner-al-pedir-un-entero-nextint-y-despues-un-string-nextline/163985#163985) pon `entrada.nextLine();`

Comment: Si he probado con nextLine() pero aún así en la segunda vuelta se queda vacío.

Comment: lo pusiste asi? `nombre = entrada.next();` `entrada.nextLine();`

Comment: Si lo hago así ahora, en la primera vuelta tengo que darle 2 veces al ENTER para que lo coja y las demás vueltas lo coge bien.

Comment: quizá debas hacer uso de una sola instancia de la clase Scanner y no una por cada método [Ejemplo](https://www.codiva.io/p/becefa06-be27-4d78-878f-c48469f6811a)