# Error (ciclo while) al leer datos seguidos (o en serie) por teclado Java

Tags: java, netbeans, bucles

Me pasa que cuando pido al usuario que ingrese datos si los pido continuos, sin después agregarle una condición o usarlos para algo los lee mal.
Ejemplo del ejercicio: Se lee desde teclado información de libros de una biblioteca. De cada libro se lee: código,
título, autor y año de edición. La lectura finaliza cuando llega el libro con código 1234, el cual
no debe procesarse. Informar:...

El problema es que si hago:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingresar codigo del libro: ");
codigo=in.nextInt();
while(codigo != 1234){
System.out.println("Ingresar titulo del libro: ");
titulo=in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Ingresar autor: ");
autor=in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Ingresar año de edición: ");
añoEdicion=in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Ingresar codigo del libro: ");
codigo=in.nextInt();}   //para evitar un bucle infinito
}}
```

LO LEE ASÍ:

```
Ingresar codigo del libro: 
3453 //DATO INGRESADO
Ingresar titulo del libro: 
Ingresar autor: //pasa a pedir autor (donde sí deja ingresar el dato)
```

Pide ingresar titulo, pero se lo salta sin leer y pasa a pedir autor donde se puede ingresar el dato, después el código sigue corriendo pidiendo datos hasta que llega a pedir titulo y se vuelve a hacer el mismo error y así hasta que se ingresa el código 1234 y termina.

No sé cómo pedirlos correctamente, así continuos, sencillos porque es el principio del tema ciclos de la carrera y siempre tengo el mismo error! Ojalá me pueden ayudar, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: debes limpirar el [buffer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163982/error-con-scanner-al-pedir-un-entero-nextint-y-despues-un-string-nextline/163985#163985)

Comment: No sabía que eso podía pasar. Gracias, ya lo pude solucionar!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que debes limpiar el buffer para poder ingresar los siguientes valores. Lo puedes realizar llamando [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) después de obtener datos numéricos, en este caso `codigo` que es tipo `int`  ), cuando a continuación ingresaras datos tipo `String`.

> [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) Avanza este escáner más allá de la línea actual y
> devuelve la entrada que se omitió. Este método devuelve el resto de la
> línea actual, excluyendo cualquier separador de línea al final. La
> posición se establece al comienzo de la siguiente línea.

por lo tanto este sería el código:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingresar codigo del libro: ");       
codigo = in.nextInt();

in.nextLine(); //* Limpia buffer

while (codigo != 1234) {
    System.out.println("Ingresar titulo del libro: ");
    titulo = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresar autor: ");
    autor = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresar año de edición: ");
    añoEdicion = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingresar codigo del libro: ");
    codigo = in.nextInt();
    
    in.nextLine();  //* Limpia buffer
    
}   //para evitar un bucle infinito
```