# Me podrian decir en que estoy mal o corregir este codigo, porfavor(Codigo de Java, bluej)

Tags: java, switch, bluej

Este codigo me lo dejaron en la escuela, no pude encontrar el error o donde se ubicaba; podian ayudarme, por favor Trata de una paleteria el cual pide nombre y numero del client; despues le da 4 opciones para la compra de sus diferentes productos con su respectivo precio y cantidad, y dentro de cada uno abre otros 2 submenus los cuales son para pedir corte de caja o ticket y al final es una opcion para salir de todo
This code was left to me at school, I could not find the error or where it was located, could they help me? please

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Examen_tipo2{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner dato=new Scanner(System.in);
        int o, c, p, a, b, e, d, f, l, n, g, i,t, u, z;
        String nom;
        System.out.print("Por favor, ingrese su nombre: ");
        nom=dato.next();
        System.out.println("Ingrese su numero de cliente");
        c=dato.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Bienvenido a neveria El Piwi");
        System.out.println("A continuacion se le mostrara un menu con 4 opciones, por favor seleccione un numero del 1 al 4 para lo que usted eliga");
        o=dato.nextInt();
        switch (o) {
        case '1':
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Cliente no.: " + c);
            System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nom);
            System.out.println("Tecle la cantidad de Paletas de Agua que desea comprar: ");
            p=dato.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion 'a' como se le muestra si quiere generar el ticket de su compra  o la 'b' como se le muestra si quiere el corte del dia");
            a=dato.nextInt();
            if (a==a){
                System.out.println("Neveria EL Piwi");
                System.out.println("Ticket");
                System.out.println("Numero del cliente: " +c);
                System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: " +nom);
                System.out.println("Cantidad de productos adquiridos en general: " +p);
                System.out.println("Cantidad total a pagar: " +f);
                System.out.println("Gracias por su compra");
            }
            if (a==b){
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Corte del dia");
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de agua vendidas: " +p);
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de leche: " + l);
                System.out.println("Total de nieves vendidas: " + n);
                System.out.println("Total de aguas vendidas: " +g);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de leche vendidas: " +f);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de agua vendidas: " +t);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de nieves vendidas: " + i);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de aguas vendidas: " +u);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de venta: " +o);
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Cliente no.: " + c);
            System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nom);
            System.out.println("Tecle la cantidad de Paletas de leche que desea comprar: ");
            l=dato.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion 'a' como se le muestra si quiere generar el ticket de su compra  o la 'b' como se le muestra si quiere el corte del dia");
            a=dato.nextInt();
            if (a==a){
                System.out.println("Neveria EL Piwi");
                System.out.println("Ticket");
                System.out.println("Numero del cliente: " +c);
                System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: " +nom);
                System.out.println("Cantidad de productos adquiridos en general: " +l);
                System.out.println("Cantidad total a pagar: " +f);
                System.out.println("Gracias por su compra");
            }
            if (a==b){
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Corte del dia");
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de agua vendidas: " +p);
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de leche: " + l);
                System.out.println("Total de nieves vendidas: " + n);
                System.out.println("Total de aguas vendidas: " +g);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de leche vendidas: " +f);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de agua vendidas: " +t);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de nieves vendidas: " + i);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de aguas vendidas: " +u);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de venta: " +o);
            }
            break;
        case '3':
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Cliente no.: " + c);
            System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nom);
            System.out.println("Tecle la cantidad de Nieves que desea comprar: ");
            n=dato.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion 'a' como se le muestra si quiere generar el ticket de su compra  o la 'b' como se le muestra si quiere el corte del dia");
            a=dato.nextInt();
            if (a==a){
                System.out.println("Neveria EL Piwi");
                System.out.println("Ticket");
                System.out.println("Numero del cliente: " +c);
                System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: " +nom);
                System.out.println("Cantidad de productos adquiridos en general: " +n);
                System.out.println("Cantidad total a pagar: " +f);
                System.out.println("Gracias por su compra");
            }
            if (a==b){
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Corte del dia");
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de agua vendidas: " +p);
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de leche: " + l);
                System.out.println("Total de nieves vendidas: " + n);
                System.out.println("Total de aguas vendidas: " +g);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de leche vendidas: " +f);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de agua vendidas: " +t);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de nieves vendidas: " + i);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de aguas vendidas: " +u);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de venta: " +o);
            }
            break;
        case '4':
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Cliente no.: " + c);
            System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nom);
            System.out.println("Tecle la cantidad de Agua que desea comprar: ");
            g=dato.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion 'a' como se le muestra si quiere generar el ticket de su compra  o la 'b' como se le muestra si quiere el corte del dia");
            a=dato.nextInt();
            if (a==a){
                System.out.println("Neveria EL Piwi");
                System.out.println("Ticket");
                System.out.println("Numero del cliente: " +c);
                System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: " +nom);
                System.out.println("Cantidad de productos adquiridos en general: " +g);
                System.out.println("Cantidad total a pagar: " +f);
                System.out.println("Gracias por su compra");
            }
            if (a==b){
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Corte del dia");
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de agua vendidas: " +p);
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de leche: " + l);
                System.out.println("Total de nieves vendidas: " + n);
                System.out.println("Total de aguas vendidas: " +g);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de leche vendidas: " +f);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de agua vendidas: " +t);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de nieves vendidas: " + i);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de aguas vendidas: " +u);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de venta: " +o);
            }
        f= 12 * p;
        e= 17 * n;
        d= 22 * p;
        g= 20 * l;
        z= u + t + i +g;
            default:System.out.print("Error, por favor tecle solamente del 1 a 4");
    }
    
}
}

``
```

Comment: por que en cada case colocas comillas simples si estas validando números??  nextInt es para capturar números si pedís ingresas a o b deberías usar solo next y usar equals en vez de ==

Comment: En [es.so] se responde a preguntas con problemas _concretos_. ¿Cuál es el comportamiento esperado? ¿Cuál es el obtenido? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Hola Diego, te sugiero revises https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java  , https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163982/error-con-scanner-al-pedir-un-entero-nextint-y-despues-un-string-nextline/163985#163985 ., saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás obteniendo un dato de tipo `int` y este lo vas a usar para obtener una opción de tu `switch` debes usar valores enteros no String (entre comillas), esta es la razón por la que no obtienes ninguna de las 4 opciones, cambia a que tu `switch` use los valores tipo `int`:

```
  o=dato.nextInt();
  switch (o) {        
        case 1:
        ...
        case 2:
        ...
        case 3:
        ...
```

otro error es que tratas de obtener un valor de tipo int y lo tratas de comparar con un tipo String:

```
 a=dato.nextInt(); //* Obtiene valor int, nunca vas a obtener "a"
 if (a==a){
```

mejor declara el valor de a y b como String, obten el valor usando  `a=dato.nextLine();` y comparas las cadenas usando `.equals()` :

```
    String a="", b="";
    ...
    ...
        //a=dato.nextInt();
        //if (a==a){
        a=dato.nextLine();
        if (a.equals("a")){
```

Recuerda también que después de obtener un valor numerico, si vas a obtener un valor de cadena, debes limpiar el buffer usando:

```
dato.nextLine();
```

---

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner dato = new Scanner(System.in);
    int o = 0, c = 0, p = 0, e = 0, d = 0, f = 0, l = 0, n = 0, g = 0, i = 0, t = 0, u = 0, z = 0;
    String a = "", b = "";
    String nom;
    System.out.print("Por favor, ingrese su nombre: ");
    nom = dato.next();
    System.out.println("Ingrese su numero de cliente");
    c = dato.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Bienvenido a neveria El Piwi");
    System.out.println("A continuacion se le mostrara un menu con 4 opciones, por favor seleccione un numero del 1 al 4 para lo que usted eliga");
    o = dato.nextInt();
    switch (o) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Cliente no.: " + c);
            System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nom);
            System.out.println("Tecle la cantidad de Paletas de Agua que desea comprar: ");
            p = dato.nextInt();
            dato.nextLine();//*Limpia buffer.
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion 'a' como se le muestra si quiere generar el ticket de su compra  o la 'b' como se le muestra si quiere el corte del dia");
            a = dato.nextLine();
            if (a.equals("a")) {
                System.out.println("Neveria EL Piwi");
                System.out.println("Ticket");
                System.out.println("Numero del cliente: " + c);
                System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: " + nom);
                System.out.println("Cantidad de productos adquiridos en general: " + p);
                System.out.println("Cantidad total a pagar: " + f);
                System.out.println("Gracias por su compra");
            }
            if (a.equals("b")) {
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Corte del dia");
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de agua vendidas: " + p);
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de leche: " + l);
                System.out.println("Total de nieves vendidas: " + n);
                System.out.println("Total de aguas vendidas: " + g);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de leche vendidas: " + f);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de agua vendidas: " + t);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de nieves vendidas: " + i);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de aguas vendidas: " + u);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de venta: " + o);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Cliente no.: " + c);
            System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nom);
            System.out.println("Tecle la cantidad de Paletas de leche que desea comprar: ");
            l = dato.nextInt();
            dato.nextLine(); //* Limpia buffer.
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion 'a' como se le muestra si quiere generar el ticket de su compra  o la 'b' como se le muestra si quiere el corte del dia");
            a = dato.nextLine();
            if (a.equals("a")) {
                System.out.println("Neveria EL Piwi");
                System.out.println("Ticket");
                System.out.println("Numero del cliente: " + c);
                System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: " + nom);
                System.out.println("Cantidad de productos adquiridos en general: " + l);
                System.out.println("Cantidad total a pagar: " + f);
                System.out.println("Gracias por su compra");
            }
            if (a == b) {
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Corte del dia");
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de agua vendidas: " + p);
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de leche: " + l);
                System.out.println("Total de nieves vendidas: " + n);
                System.out.println("Total de aguas vendidas: " + g);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de leche vendidas: " + f);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de agua vendidas: " + t);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de nieves vendidas: " + i);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de aguas vendidas: " + u);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de venta: " + o);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Cliente no.: " + c);
            System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nom);
            System.out.println("Tecle la cantidad de Nieves que desea comprar: ");
            n = dato.nextInt();
            dato.nextLine(); //* Limpia buffer.
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion 'a' como se le muestra si quiere generar el ticket de su compra  o la 'b' como se le muestra si quiere el corte del dia");
            a = dato.nextLine();
            if (a.equals("a")) {
                System.out.println("Neveria EL Piwi");
                System.out.println("Ticket");
                System.out.println("Numero del cliente: " + c);
                System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: " + nom);
                System.out.println("Cantidad de productos adquiridos en general: " + n);
                System.out.println("Cantidad total a pagar: " + f);
                System.out.println("Gracias por su compra");
            }
            if (a.equals("b")) {
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Corte del dia");
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de agua vendidas: " + p);
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de leche: " + l);
                System.out.println("Total de nieves vendidas: " + n);
                System.out.println("Total de aguas vendidas: " + g);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de leche vendidas: " + f);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de agua vendidas: " + t);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de nieves vendidas: " + i);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de aguas vendidas: " + u);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de venta: " + o);
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Cliente no.: " + c);
            System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nom);
            System.out.println("Tecle la cantidad de Agua que desea comprar: ");
            g = dato.nextInt();
            dato.nextLine(); //Limpia buffer
            System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
            System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion 'a' como se le muestra si quiere generar el ticket de su compra  o la 'b' como se le muestra si quiere el corte del dia");
            a = dato.nextLine();
            if (a.equals("a")) {
                System.out.println("Neveria EL Piwi");
                System.out.println("Ticket");
                System.out.println("Numero del cliente: " + c);
                System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: " + nom);
                System.out.println("Cantidad de productos adquiridos en general: " + g);
                System.out.println("Cantidad total a pagar: " + f);
                System.out.println("Gracias por su compra");
            }
            if (a == b) {
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Corte del dia");
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de agua vendidas: " + p);
                System.out.println("Total de paletas de leche: " + l);
                System.out.println("Total de nieves vendidas: " + n);
                System.out.println("Total de aguas vendidas: " + g);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de leche vendidas: " + f);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de agua vendidas: " + t);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de nieves vendidas: " + i);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de aguas vendidas: " + u);
                System.out.println("Total de ingreso de venta: " + o);
            }
            f = 12 * p;
            e = 17 * n;
            d = 22 * p;
            g = 20 * l;
            z = u + t + i + g;
        default:
            System.out.print("Error, por favor tecle solamente del 1 a 4");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uno de los problemas es el que te dice Jorgesys, pero otro problema es que estás diciendo que introduzca un string o char en un entero para el ticket y el corte. Además he añadido un bucle hasta que pulse una tecla. Así que te dejo una posible solución:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner dato=new Scanner(System.in);
    int o, c, p, a, b, e, d, f, l, n, g, i,t, u, z;
    o = c = p = a = b = e = d = f = l = n = g = i = t = u = z = 0;
    a = 1;
    b = 2;

    String nom;
    System.out.print("Por favor, ingrese su nombre: ");
    nom=dato.next();
    System.out.println("Ingrese su numero de cliente");
    c=dato.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Bienvenido a neveria El Piwi");
    String comprar = "Y";
    while (comprar.equals("Y") || comprar.equals("y")) {
        System.out.println("A continuacion se le mostrara un menu con 4 opciones, por favor seleccione un numero del 1 al 4 para lo que usted eliga");
        o = dato.nextInt();
        switch (o) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Cliente no.: " + c);
                System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nom);
                System.out.println("Tecle la cantidad de Paletas de Agua que desea comprar: ");
                p = dato.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion '1' como se le muestra si quiere generar el ticket de su compra  o la '2' como se le muestra si quiere el corte del dia");
                int ticketOCorte = dato.nextInt();
                if (ticketOCorte == a) {
                    System.out.println("Neveria EL Piwi");
                    System.out.println("Ticket");
                    System.out.println("Numero del cliente: " + c);
                    System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: " + nom);
                    System.out.println("Cantidad de productos adquiridos en general: " + p);
                    System.out.println("Cantidad total a pagar: " + f);
                    System.out.println("Gracias por su compra");
                }
                if (ticketOCorte == b) {
                    System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                    System.out.println("Corte del dia");
                    System.out.println("Total de paletas de agua vendidas: " + p);
                    System.out.println("Total de paletas de leche: " + l);
                    System.out.println("Total de nieves vendidas: " + n);
                    System.out.println("Total de aguas vendidas: " + g);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de leche vendidas: " + f);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de agua vendidas: " + t);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de nieves vendidas: " + i);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de aguas vendidas: " + u);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de venta: " + o);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Cliente no.: " + c);
                System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nom);
                System.out.println("Tecle la cantidad de Paletas de leche que desea comprar: ");
                l = dato.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion '1' como se le muestra si quiere generar el ticket de su compra  o la '2' como se le muestra si quiere el corte del dia");
                ticketOCorte = dato.nextInt();
                if (ticketOCorte == a) {
                    System.out.println("Neveria EL Piwi");
                    System.out.println("Ticket");
                    System.out.println("Numero del cliente: " + c);
                    System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: " + nom);
                    System.out.println("Cantidad de productos adquiridos en general: " + l);
                    System.out.println("Cantidad total a pagar: " + f);
                    System.out.println("Gracias por su compra");
                }
                if (ticketOCorte == b) {
                    System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                    System.out.println("Corte del dia");
                    System.out.println("Total de paletas de agua vendidas: " + p);
                    System.out.println("Total de paletas de leche: " + l);
                    System.out.println("Total de nieves vendidas: " + n);
                    System.out.println("Total de aguas vendidas: " + g);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de leche vendidas: " + f);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de agua vendidas: " + t);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de nieves vendidas: " + i);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de aguas vendidas: " + u);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de venta: " + o);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Cliente no.: " + c);
                System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nom);
                System.out.println("Tecle la cantidad de Nieves que desea comprar: ");
                n = dato.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion '1' como se le muestra si quiere generar el ticket de su compra  o la '2' como se le muestra si quiere el corte del dia");
                ticketOCorte = dato.nextInt();
                if (ticketOCorte == a) {
                    System.out.println("Neveria EL Piwi");
                    System.out.println("Ticket");
                    System.out.println("Numero del cliente: " + c);
                    System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: " + nom);
                    System.out.println("Cantidad de productos adquiridos en general: " + n);
                    System.out.println("Cantidad total a pagar: " + f);
                    System.out.println("Gracias por su compra");
                }
                if (ticketOCorte == b) {
                    System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                    System.out.println("Corte del dia");
                    System.out.println("Total de paletas de agua vendidas: " + p);
                    System.out.println("Total de paletas de leche: " + l);
                    System.out.println("Total de nieves vendidas: " + n);
                    System.out.println("Total de aguas vendidas: " + g);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de leche vendidas: " + f);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de agua vendidas: " + t);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de nieves vendidas: " + i);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de aguas vendidas: " + u);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de venta: " + o);
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Cliente no.: " + c);
                System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nom);
                System.out.println("Tecle la cantidad de Agua que desea comprar: ");
                g = dato.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion '1' como se le muestra si quiere generar el ticket de su compra  o la '2' como se le muestra si quiere el corte del dia");
                ticketOCorte = dato.nextInt();
                if (ticketOCorte == a) {
                    System.out.println("Neveria EL Piwi");
                    System.out.println("Ticket");
                    System.out.println("Numero del cliente: " + c);
                    System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: " + nom);
                    System.out.println("Cantidad de productos adquiridos en general: " + g);
                    System.out.println("Cantidad total a pagar: " + f);
                    System.out.println("Gracias por su compra");
                }
                if (ticketOCorte == b) {
                    System.out.println("Neveria El Piwi");
                    System.out.println("Corte del dia");
                    System.out.println("Total de paletas de agua vendidas: " + p);
                    System.out.println("Total de paletas de leche: " + l);
                    System.out.println("Total de nieves vendidas: " + n);
                    System.out.println("Total de aguas vendidas: " + g);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de leche vendidas: " + f);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de paletas de agua vendidas: " + t);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de nieves vendidas: " + i);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de aguas vendidas: " + u);
                    System.out.println("Total de ingreso de venta: " + o);
                }
                f = 12 * p;
                e = 17 * n;
                d = 22 * p;
                g = 20 * l;
                z = u + t + i + g;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("Error, por favor tecle solamente del 1 a 4");
        }
        System.out.println("Desea continuar comprando, pulse Y o y, si no desea comprar más pulse otra tecla.");
        comprar = dato.next();
    }
}
```