# Problema con scanner en java "next() y nextLine()"

Tags: java, visual-studio, scanner, java-util-scanner

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente trozo de codigo:

```
System.out.println("introduce el id");
libro1.setId(input.nextInt());
System.out.println("Introduce el titulo ");
libro1.setLibro(input.next());
System.out.println("introduce el autor");
libro1.setAutor(input.next());
System.out.println("introduce la editorial");
libro1.setEditorial(input.next());
```

Y tengo un problema y es que a la hora de introducir datos de tipo `string` me esta haciendo cosas raras, lo que yo quiero hacer seria lo siguiente:

```
System.out.println("introduce el id");
#1
System.out.println("Introduce el titulo ");
#El mago de oz
System.out.println("introduce el autor");
#Lyman Frank Baum
System.out.println("introduce la editorial");
#anaya
```

Cuando introduzco el id no tengo problema pongo un `int` y sin problemas pero a la hora de hacer el primer `string` empiezan los problemas, y la salida que me da al introducir "El mago de oz" es el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        at App.main(App.java:23)
```

He estado buscando y porque el `next()` en el scanner usa como delimitador los espacion en blanco lo que me ha llegado a otra posible solucion la cual es usar `nextLine()` pero entonces me surgue otro problema que es que la salida que me da despues de sustituir todos los `next()` por `nextLine()` es la siguiente:

```
introduce el id
1
Introduce el titulo 
introduce el autor
El mago de oz
introduce la editorial
anaya
```

Y como ovbiamente se ve que se ha omitido el titulo ya que cuando veo los datos guardados el titulo no esta porque es como si ese scanner hubiese despareccido.
Despues de un buen rato buscando he encontrado varias paginas que indican que el `nextLine()` lee los datos hasta que hay un salto de linea y el `next()` hasta que hay un espacio en blanco por lo que me daba ese error ya que esta asignando "El" a titulo "mago" a autor y asi hasta que se sale del indice, pero con `nextLine()` en teoria no deberia dar problemas y mucho menos saltarse una linea de codigo sin ninguna orden que lo indique. Probe tambien a cambiar el delimitador del `next()` y que el delimitador sea un salto de linea y es como si la orden no la usase la orden que use fue `input.useDelimiter("\n")` y nada seguia haciendo lo mismo, si alguien sabe que tengo que hacer para poder introducir esa salida y si es necesario que cambie el orden y ponga primero el titulo y el id ultimo o algo asi que me lo diga estare muy agradecido gracias

PD: dejo aqui el codigo completo (main) por si alguien me quiere correguir alguna cosa:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean exit = false;
        boolean exit2 = false;
        int option = 0;
        int option2 = 0;
        int buscarID = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<libro> libros = new ArrayList();
        Iterator<libro> it = libros.iterator();
        

        while(!exit){
            
            System.out.println("1. Introducir un libro");
            System.out.println("2. Imprimir libros almacenados");
            System.out.println("3. Buscar un libro por su id");
            System.out.println("4. Salir");
             
            System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
            option = input.nextInt();
             
            switch(option){
                case 1:
                    libro libro1 = new libro();
                    System.out.println("introduce el id");
                    libro1.setId(input.nextInt());
                    System.out.println("Introduce el titulo ");
                    libro1.setLibro(input.next());
                    System.out.println("introduce el autor");
                    libro1.setAutor(input.next());
                    System.out.println("introduce la editorial");
                    libro1.setEditorial(input.next());

                    libros.add(libro1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (libros.size() == 0){
                        System.out.println("Aun no se ha introducido ningun libro");
                    }
                    else{
                        for(int i = 0;i<libros.size();i++){
                            System.out.println(libros.get(i).toString());
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                 case 3:
                    exit2=false;
                    while(!exit2){
                        System.out.println("1. Buscar usando for");
                        System.out.println("2. Buscar usando for each");
                        System.out.println("3. Buscar usando iterator");
                        System.out.println("4. Salir");

                        System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
                        option2 = input.nextInt();

                        switch(option2){
                            case 1: //Buscar con FOR
                                buscarID = 0;
                                System.out.println("introduce el ID del libro que quieras buscar");
                                buscarID = input.nextInt();
                                for(int i = 0;i<libros.size();i++){
                                    if (libros.get(i).getId()==buscarID){
                                        System.out.println("El libro que buscas es: "+libros.get(i).toString());
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if (i == libros.size()-1){
                                            System.out.println("El libro no existe");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            case 2://Buscar con FOR EACH
                                buscarID = 0;
                                System.out.println("introduce el ID del libro que quieras buscar");
                                buscarID = input.nextInt();
                                for(int i = 0;i<libros.size();i++){
                                    if (libros.get(i).getId()==buscarID){
                                        System.out.println("El libro que buscas es: "+libros.get(i).toString());
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if (i == libros.size()-1){
                                            System.out.println("El libro no existe");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3://Buscar con iterator
                                buscarID = 0;
                                System.out.println("introduce el ID del libro que quieras buscar");
                                buscarID = input.nextInt();
                                while (it.hasNext()){
                                    if (it.next().getId() == buscarID){
                                        System.out.println("El libro que buscas es: "+it.next().toString());
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        System.out.println("El libro no se ha añadido");
                                }
                                break;       
                                }
                            case 4:
                                exit2=true;
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Solo números entre 1 y 4");   
                            }
                        }

                    break;
                 case 4:
                    exit=true;
                    break;
                 default:
                    System.out.println("Solo números entre 1 y 4");
            }
             
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Y el codigo de la clase libro:

```
public class libro {
    private int id;
    private String libro;
    private String autor;
    private String editorial;

    public libro() {
    }

    public libro(int id, String libro, String autor, String editorial) {
        this.id = id;
        this.libro = libro;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.editorial = editorial;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLibro() {
        return libro;
    }

    public void setLibro(String libro) {
        this.libro = libro;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public String getEditorial() {
        return editorial;
    }

    public void setEditorial(String editorial) {
        this.editorial = editorial;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "libro [id=" + id + ", libro=" + libro + ", autor=" + autor + ", editorial=" + editorial + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: debes limpiar el [buffer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163982/error-con-scanner-al-pedir-un-entero-nextint-y-despues-un-string-nextline/163985#163985) del scanner

Comment: Como se hace eso?

Comment: basicamente usa pon input.nextLine(); luego de libro1.setId(input.nextInt()); para limpiar el buffer y usa libro1.setLibro(input.nextLine()); para capturar el titulo

Comment: en el primer comentario que hice dale click a la palabra resaltada buffer para que te rediriga a una pregunta relacionada con la tuya, donde se detalla lo que intento explicar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He estado probando tu código, y puedo decir lo siguiente:

Si usas "input.next()", efectivamente tienes el problema del delimitador por defecto, que es el espacio. Para evitarlo, como comentabas tú mismo, puedes usar "nextLine()".

En este caso, encontramos otro comportamiento extraño, y la razón es que "nextInt()" no está "consumiendo" el salto de línea por lo que el primer "nextLine()" que haces simplemente encuentra una línea en blanco y pasa al siguiente.

La solución, aunque no sé si es la ideal, pasa por añadir un "input.nextLine()" después de cada "input.nextInt()":

```
Libro libro1 = new Libro();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("introduce el id");
libro1.setId(input.nextInt());

input.nextLine(); //Aquí

System.out.println("Introduce el titulo");
libro1.setTitulo(input.next());

System.out.println("introduce el autor");
libro1.setAutor(input.next());

System.out.println("introduce la editorial");
libro1.setEditorial(input.next());

input.close();
```